# GeoServer GetCapabilties shows wrong OnlineResourse: URL

Tags: geoserver, wms, getcapabilities

In my GeoServer WMS GetCapabilities document all layers have an onlineResource parameter which ends with "wms?SERVICE=WMS&" instead of just "wms?". This has the effect that I can´t cascade my GeoServer layers with other systems as cascading is quite sensitive to irregularities.

Can anyone tell if this is normal or is it a bug in GeoServer 2.5?

Does it correspond to the OGC WMS standard?

and can I change the GetCapabilities in GeoServer per hand?

Comment: It's a feature of all geoserver software.

Answer (score 2):

You mean that your WMS is really reading the GetCapabilities from the cascaded WMS? The servers I mostly use do not bother and they trust blindly to what is configured but I am remembering that ArcGIS server may be an exception.

However, it is acceptable to advertise a GetMap URL that is different from the base URL and even it is odd to include ?SERVICE=WMS into the onlineResourse I do not believe that it is against the standard. What is important is that the service works if the WMS parameters are added to the base URL and Geoservers do work as you can test

http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&WIDTH=459&HEIGHT=353&LAYERS=topp%3Astates&RANSPARENT=TRUE&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&BBOX=-125.964082115,14.004707960577342,-65.737188885,60.32299403942266&SRS=EPSG:4326&STYLES=

You can see that the SERVICE=WMS appears two times in the request but it does not make any harm. I would say that the cascading WMS is the one that does not follow the standard.

Comment: The cascading geodata server is deegree. My job is to simply deliver wms services to the organisation using the deegree server. There are many other organisations which are being cascaded in deegree and the problem lies only with my wms services. My WMS Service does not get cascaded when the wms-url and the url in the onlineResource parameter in the Getcapabilities document differs. With ArcGIS Server I can manually change the onlineResource parameter. In Geoserver I can´t see how to.

Comment: IMHO the GetCapabilities response of Geoserver is valid and deegree has traditionally tried to follow the standard literally. Thus I believe that there is a way to configure deegree so that cascading works but deegree is somewhat painful to configure. I would recommend to ask from deegree users mailing list how to do it and ask them to make configuration for the demo.opengeo.org site as a model.

Answer (score 2):

> and can I change the GetCapabilities in GeoServer per hand?

No, but what you can do is take a copy of the GetCapabilities response and edit the onlineResource parameter value to just `wms?` for the GetMap and other operations, except the GetCapabilites which would be a reference to itself (the static file you create and host on a public web site). Then point the cascading server to the static file.